# How can I tell if a side event is timed or missable?

Tags: tales-of-xillia

After arriving in Auj Oule and spending time there for a bit, I've come across some sub events. I've completed The Monster Lies buy going to the lake twice and defeated some monsters there.

I've also come across a Fruit Seller where someone wants a Porange. I can't complete this one at this time, at looked up where to acquire a Porange later in the game. I don't know how to tell if this needs to be completed within a certain amount of time or before some event in the game.

My issue is that these two quests look similar in the menu and there are always missable side events in Tales games. Tales of Vesperia constantly had me completing side quests at certain times for important artes. Is there a way for me to know which ones are missable or must be completed within a certain amount of time? Do I just have to constantly follow a guide for all of these events outside the game like Vesperia?

Comment: It's been a good while since I played Xillia... but I don't remember it being as unforgiving as Vesperia in the 'missable content' aspect. Not nearly. Some subevents are missable, but IIRC it doesn't impact the ability to get artes/weapons/etc. I'll go confirm before writing up a whole answer with wrong info...